# pip install --no-index can't find local archive for django-signals-ahoy==0.1-3

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm running into a problem using `pip install` to install a specific package from a local archive (a wheel to be exact) with `--no-index`. The package is shown exactly as `pip freeze` outputs it:

`pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/resources/wheels django-signals-ahoy==0.1-3`

The wheel isn't the issue. It's there, and it works. For instance, the following line DOES work:

`pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/resources/wheels django-signals-ahoy`

I need the first line to work, however, because I use `pip freeze > requirements.txt' and requirements.txt will have`django-signals-ahoy==0.1-3`.

If I remove `--no-index` from the first line then it works, but that's not a valid answer for this case because the whole point of using `--no-index` is to prevent pip from hitting indexes and instead just install from local archives instead, as is documented here: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels

Note that I have several packages that do install using this approach... this one package seems to be an outlier :/

Here's the complete output when running the first line (which fails):

```
$ pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/resources/wheels django-signals-ahoy==0.1-3
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Downloading/unpacking django-signals-ahoy==0.1-3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-signals-ahoy==0.1-3 (from     versions: 0.1_3)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for django-signals-ahoy==0.1-3
Storing complete log in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

Any ideas on how I can get pip to work with django-signals-ahoy==0.1-3?

Comment: `0.1-3` is not a valid version string if I'm not mistaken. Could you rename the version and install it that way?

Comment: Do you mean rename the whl file or the requirements.txt file? The whl file is: django_signals_ahoy-0.1_3-py2-none-any.whl

Comment: Basically everywhere that version number shows up (filename, requirements).